# Divergence of gradient of vector field

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I start with the following product that Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Dyadic.2C_outer.2C_and_tensor_products) calls a dyadic product, or outer product, or tensor product. In 3D Cartesian coordinates, it looks like this:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \mathbf{v} = \nabla \otimes \mathbf{v} = \nabla \mathbf{v}^T = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1} &
\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_1} &
\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_1} \\ 
\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2} &
\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2} &
\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_2} \\ 
\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_3} &
\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_3} &
\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_3} \\ 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{equation}

I am wondering how to reduce the divergence of this object to a simpler form:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v}
\end{equation}

I believe that this reduces to the following:
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v} = \nabla^2 \mathbf{v}
\end{equation}

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most people would interpret that as $\nabla^2\mathbf{v}$. However, it is somewhat ambiguous, and could be interpreted as $\boldsymbol\nabla(\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v})$ depending on your convention for tensor divergence.

Or, in summation notation, there is ambiguity as to whether $\boldsymbol\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol \nabla \mathbf{v}$ means $\partial_i\partial_i v_j$ or $\partial_i\partial_jv_i$.

Comment: In the context in which I am using it, the divergence means the first of your two summations. I assume the first summation is for del^2 v and the second summation is del (del dot v)? Perhaps I should clarify in my question?

Comment: Yes, that is the case. $\nabla^2 \mathbf{v} = \partial_i\partial_iv_j$ and $\boldsymbol\nabla\boldsymbol\nabla \cdot\mathbf{v} = \partial_i\partial_jv_i$.